# how to add repitition index and unstack in pandas?

Tags: pandas

dataframe as follows:

```
time         a   b   c   d   e
2006/1/16   249 249 250 250 251
2006/2/15   254 253 255 255 255
2006/3/16   261 261 262 262 264
2006/4/16   272 271 273 273 274
2006/5/16   282 281 283 283 283
2006/6/16   288 287 289 289 289
2006/7/16   292 292 293 293 293
2006/8/16   290 290 291 291 292
2006/9/16   282 281 283 283 284
2006/10/16  271 270 272 272 273
2006/11/16  259 258 260 260 261
2006/12/16  251 251 252 252 253
2007/1/16   247 247 247 248 250
2007/2/15   253 253 254 254 255
2007/3/16   261 261 262 262 264
2007/4/16   273 272 274 274 275
2007/5/16   282 281 283 283 283
2007/6/16   288 288 290 289 290
2007/7/16   292 292 293 293 294
2007/8/16   291 290 291 291 292
2007/9/16   282 282 283 283 284
2007/10/16  271 270 272 272 273
2007/11/16  260 259 261 261 262
```

I want to unstack as

```
 a          1  2   3  4  5   6   7  8  9  10  11  12
     2006    .......................................
     2007    .......................................

 b   2006    .......................................
     2007    .......................................

             .......................................
 c   2006

 d   ...............................................

 e   2007    .......................................
```

pandas timestamps cound be apply on it？ And how to generate  `year` and `month` index if there is no `time` columns.

```
year   month
2006    1
2006    2
...     ..
2006    12
2007    1
2007    2
...    ...
2007    12
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first, then  create [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) with [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and 
[`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and assign to index. Then remove column `time` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['time'].dt.month,  df['time'].dt.year], 
                                      names=(None, None))
df = df.drop('time', axis=1).unstack(fill_value=0).T
print (df)
         1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
a 2006  249  254  261  272  282  288  292  290  282  271  259  251
  2007  247  253  261  273  282  288  292  291  282  271  260    0
b 2006  249  253  261  271  281  287  292  290  281  270  258  251
  2007  247  253  261  272  281  288  292  290  282  270  259    0
c 2006  250  255  262  273  283  289  293  291  283  272  260  252
  2007  247  254  262  274  283  290  293  291  283  272  261    0
d 2006  250  255  262  273  283  289  293  291  283  272  260  252
  2007  248  254  262  274  283  289  293  291  283  272  261    0
e 2006  251  255  264  274  283  289  293  292  284  273  261  253
  2007  250  255  264  275  283  290  294  292  284  273  262    0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd construct a new `pd.Series` from `numpy` arrays and `unstack`

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)

cols = list('abcde')
n, m = len(df), len(cols)

v = np.concatenate([df[c].values for c in cols])
i = np.repeat(cols, n)
y = np.tile(df.time.dt.year.values, m)
m = np.tile(df.time.dt.month.values, m)

pd.Series(v, pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([i, y, m])).unstack(fill_value=0)

         1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
a 2006  249  254  261  272  282  288  292  290  282  271  259  251
  2007  247  253  261  273  282  288  292  291  282  271  260    0
b 2006  249  253  261  271  281  287  292  290  281  270  258  251
  2007  247  253  261  272  281  288  292  290  282  270  259    0
c 2006  250  255  262  273  283  289  293  291  283  272  260  252
  2007  247  254  262  274  283  290  293  291  283  272  261    0
d 2006  250  255  262  273  283  289  293  291  283  272  260  252
  2007  248  254  262  274  283  289  293  291  283  272  261    0
e 2006  251  255  264  274  283  289  293  292  284  273  261  253
  2007  250  255  264  275  283  290  294  292  284  273  262    0
```

Comment: It looks lile add auxiliary columns using  `repeat` year and `tile` month.

Comment: @Cobin What do you mean?

Comment: The way of adding new columns for unstack is easy to me.

Comment: @Cobin You could generate the cartesian product with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2006, 2007], range(1, 13)])` however, you're  missing `2007-12` from your dataset.

Comment: @Cobin or you could produce a `time` column with `pd.date_range('2006-01-31', periods=23, freq='M')`

Comment: Yes,  It is merely applied on  unbroken data. If there is any missing in dataframe, it is disabled. . Using datetime is more efficient. Both of U give me  wants help. Thanks.